# Switch Map под капотом

Tags: rxjs

Как технически срабатывает Switch Map?
Что конкретно происходит для того, чтобы отменить уже посланный с сервера на клиент запрос?

Comment: Да, спасибо, я имел в виду, технически, кто его отменяет? Браузер, RxJS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switchMap` не имеет никакого отношения к запросам.

Это делает `HttpClient`. При создании потока можно вернуть функцию, которая вызовется при отписке, это сделано для удобства и избежания утечек памяти.

```
new Observable((observer) => {
  function listener(event: MouseEvent) {
    observer.next(event);
  }

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', listener);

  return () => window.removeEventListener('mousemove', listener);
});
```

`HttpClient` использует `XMLHttpRequest` у которого есть метод `abort`, он и прерывает запрос если отписаться до того как пришел ответ.

```
new Observable((observer) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', '/api/delay', true);

  xhr.onload = () => observer.next(xhr.responseText);

  xhr.send();

  return () => xhr.abort();
});
```

Если подписаться и сразу же отписаться то запрос будет отменен.

`switchMap` слушает 2 потока - источник (`source`) и проекцию (`project`). При генерации события источником `switchMap` подписывается на проекцию и ждет генерации события уже от проекции. Если следующее событие от источника придет раньше чем событие от проекции - `switchMap` отписывается от проекции и создает новую подписку.

Comment: Суппер! Понял, спасибо!